# Sharepoint Online Site Columns not available in Flow Dynamic Content

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column, flow

I have created a site lookup column (with 2 additional columns) on my parent site.  I'm using this site lookup column on a list in a child site to populate location.  I have created a Flow to send an email when a new item is created in the child's list.  I want to include the location in the body of the email, but it is not available in the dynamic content sections of Flow.  I have already checked that I am not using the Location (linked to item) at the parent level and beyond.  Does anyone know how to get this type of information from SharePoint to be available in Flow?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the SharePoint List item action in Flow right?
For better working with fields and so one use **HTTP request and create REST API** get to the SharePoint list, I always using it this way.

Answer (score -1):

In the dynamic contents window in Flow, select "see more" to show all of the columns.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I tried, but I still don't see it.  Does it matter that the field is not called "Title"